# C# ASP.NET - Web service funciona en Win 7 pero no en Win 2012 Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

Hice un desarrollo en C# ASPX sobre una plataforma Win 7 y en ésta los web services (REST) funcionan perfecto. Recientemente hice el deploy en un Win 2012 Server y tengo un WS en especial que trae el cambio del dólar (TRM) desde Banco de la República (Colombia). Funciona sin problemas en la plataforma de desarrollo, pero en el Win 2012 server genera el siguiente error:

> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.] 
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8442708
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +234
>
> [EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://localhost/trm_ban_rep.asmx that could accept the message. This
>   is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See
>   InnerException, if present, for more details.]
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14581778
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) +622
>   WebApplication1.ref_trm_ban_rep.trm_ban_repSoap.trm() +0
>   WebApplication1.master.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +126
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3178

Quiero recalcar que este WS funciona perfectamente en mi plataforma Win 7.

Mi pregunta es: Posiblemente, ¿es un tema de configuración del server, de puertos o el firewall?

Gracias por su amable tiempo.

Comment: ¿Qué version del .Net Framework estas utilizando para tu proyecto de WebService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el momento que te envía este error:

> [EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/trm_ban_rep.asmx

Siginifica que tu nuevo servicio está buscando una ruta en `localhost`, es por eso que localmente funciona sin problema.

En el archivo **web.config** de tu servidor cambia el `address` de tu **EndPoint** por el indicado donde se encuentra publicado, algo así más o menos:

```
<endpoint address="http://URLDeTuServicio/trm_ban_rep.asmx"/>
```

Comment: justo lo que estaba por publicar

Comment: @fredyfx jejeje :D

Comment: Cambie el web.config como lo mencionaste y funcionó perfecto. Algo importante, si el sitio web se creo con un puerto específico, se le debe agregar a la url del servicio. Ejemplo: <endpoint address="http://URLDeTuServicio:XXXX/trm_ban_rep.asmx"/>

Comment: @AlexanderPachón exacto, debes especificar el número de puerto por el cual está expuesto tu servicio, saludos :D

Comment: @AlexanderPachón acepta esta respuesta por favor :D así mantenemos la salud del sitio basado en % de respuestas solucionadas :D

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te pueden estar faltando habilitar algunas características del *IIS* en el servidor. Yo empezaría por comparar las características que están habilitadas en el entorno local y las compararía con las del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, ese error sale cuando el servicio al cual estas intentando invocar, no está disponible, esto puede ser porque el servidor no está arriba o bien porque si estas invocando a un servicio que estas desarrollando no se está ejecutando.
Si su servicio esta en el IIS local, le recomiendo que vaya al administradir de IIS y reinicie el servidor o bien por consola con persmidos de administrador (Presionar tecla windows, teclear cmd, hacer click derecho sobre el ícono, ejecutar como administrador), ejecutar el siguiente comando **iisreset**. 
Saludos.